# Make bins with range

Tags: python, list, range

I have an array of non-negative integers, the smallest of which is `min_val`, and the largest of which is `max_val`. I want to use `range` to make a list of bin boundaries with a given `step`, such that the first value in the range is equal to `min_val`, and that the last value in the range is greater than `max_val`. My attempt is:

```
bins = list(range(min_val, max_val + step + 1, step))
```

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is how to determine the minimum value for the second argument to `range()` that can guarantee the last value in the range is greater than `max_val`. Is my attempt correct?

Comment: If it needs to be __GREATER__ as opposed to greater than or equal to, change 1 to 2, otherwise it's fine

Comment: "Greater than" (>) or "greater than or equal" (>=) than `max_val`?

Comment: @Jerfov2 It needs to be greater than (>). Why 2?

Comment: @Elmex80s Greater than (>).

Comment: @ZizhengTai range doesn't include the second parameter in the return values

Comment: Not exactly sure what @Jerfov2 claims but `range(6, 11 + 3 + 2, 3)` gives `[6, 9, 12, 15]` which is undesired because because you want `12` to be the largest value in the list. The code in the question is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Lets forget the `range` function for now. With an upper limit (upper limit included) of `max_val + step` you guarantee the last step taken is larger than (>) `max_val`, because if it would stop at `max_val` then you could do another step of size `step` because `max_val + step` is the upper limit.

Now the range functions stops stepping before (<) the 2nd paramater. So if your upper limit is `max_val + step` you must add 1 to it so you have `max_val + step + 1`.

Note that this is incorrect code:

```
>>> range(6, 11 + 3 + 2, 3) 
[6, 9, 12, 15]
```

because you want `12` to be the largest value in the list.

This is also an incorrect result

```
>>> range(5, 11 + 3 + 0, 3)
[5, 8, 11]
```